# What is the java cometd pattern for notifying clients of server-side events?

Tags: java, push, cometd, bayeux

I'm struggling to understand an efficient way to notify clients without wasting threads. When a client connects to a CometD servlet, I want to start monitoring server-side events for the client, and publish them to the client when they are available. This should be done in a threadpool or something that doesn't use the servlet thread. All the example I see are for client originated events, and listeners on the server. I need the inverse... Do I just hand off the Client/ServerSession object to my own machinery? It seems like this would be a common pattern, but I can't find any examples.

Comment: If you are using weblogic, you have everything built-in : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/pubsub.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Servlet 3.0 Async API. In particular, `ServletRequest.startAsync()` will return you an `AsyncContext` object which you can "hand off to your own machinery", and then return from your servlet doGet()/doPost()/etc. without terminating the connection.

There are then various patterns for sending data back to the client. I believe your "own machinery" can just fetch the `ServletResponse` from the `AsyncContext` and write to it. Another approach is to call `dispatch()` on the `AsyncContext` which will cause your doGet()/doPost() method to be called again.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to use bayeux/cometd and it abstracts some of this, so it is less obvious how to handle it. I ended up using a threadpool of my own and using the subscribe/unsubscribe callbacks that Bayeux provides to schedule jobs in my pool.